# Dynamic height DIV with scrolling

Tags: css

I am trying to make a chat window that allows the area where chat messages(#messages_window below) will resize to fit the empty space between the header and input area of the chat area. When it resizes, it still needs to be scrollable.

Here is the HTML I have:

```
<div id="chat_window">
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="messages_window">

    </div>
    <div id="input_area">
        <input type="text" id="chat_input"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" style="float:right;" onclick="Javascript:sendMessage();" value="Send"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
#chat_window
{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#chat_window #header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #69acf1;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#chat_window #messages_window
{
    width: 100%;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

#input_area
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
#input_area #chat_input
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: SOrry, force of habit from so much email sending. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try positioning the `#header` and the `message_window` with `absolute`, and use `top` and `bottom` properties, like what you did with the input area:

```
#chat_window {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#chat_window #header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #69acf1;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#chat_window #messages_window {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top:30px;
    bottom:60px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#input_area {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
#input_area #chat_input {
    width: 98%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NGG7/)

The bottom and top of the `#messages_window` need to be adjusted to the heignt of the `#header` and `input_area`. The sroll bar is added automatically when content is too long (`overflow-y: auto;`).

Comment: Martin, I'm sure this will come as no surprise, but this does not work properly in IE9. The #input_area floats to the top of the DIV. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I had now the absolute positioned #header, #messages_window and #input_area break out of the scope of the #chat_window. The last should be positioned relative, to keep the others in the right place, and ahve a hight defined. I updated the code in my answer and added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7NGG7/ Hope it works now ... I did not have IE at hand right now to try it out.